# AngularJs Protractor Html Reporter Fails Config Parser

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to use protractor html screenshot reporter but it's failing to require in the the config file. Here's my config:

```
//Configuration for Protractor
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
   baseDirectory: '/screenshots',
   takeScreeenShotOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
});

exports.config = {
   //Address of Selenium server
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

   //framework: 'jasmine2',

   chromeOnly: false,

   multiCapabilities: [
       {'browserName': 'chrome'}
   ],

   //URL of the application
   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:80',
   cache: false,

   //Spec pattern
   specs: ['**/specs/*-spec.js'],

   onPrepare: function () {
       //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
       browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(480, 800);
       browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(400, 100);
       jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
   },

   //Options passed to Jasmine-node
   jasmineNodeOpts: {
       includeStackTrace: true,
       showColors: true,
       defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
       isVerbose: true,
   }
 };
```

I have both protractor and the protractor html screenshot report installed globally . Here's the error protractor is throwing:

[13:48:23] E/configParser - error code: 105
[13:48:23] E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file protractor-config.js

Any help would be most helpful!!

UPDATE:

I moved to the require call inside the onPrepare in the config and I getting the proper error:

[14:27:15] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[14:27:15] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:27:18] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter'

Seems like it can't find the node module. Anyone else seeing this issue?

UPDATE2:

So, I think I found my problem. I was installing like this:

npm install -g protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Which seems to be the cause the fail. Installing with this command:

npm install protractor-html-screenshot-reporter --save-dev

Works! For whatever reason installing globally doesn't work but installing locally does, which is a bit of a downer :( If anyone knows how to get this to work with the screenshot reporter installed globally let me know how :)

Comment: I think you should be looking into `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` instead..assuming you are using modern protractor and jasmine2.

Comment: but the node module name is protractor-html-screenshot-reporter. Here's the npm link. https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Comment: Sure, I think you are using jasmine2, `protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` would not work with it. You should look into screenshot reporter that supports jasmine2.

Comment: is the jasmine2 screenshot reporter in npm?

Comment: Sure, https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter.

Comment: Thanks for your help @alecxe :)